# append an array as a column to an pre initialized matrix

Tags: julia

I wish to use indexing to populate a pre initialized matrix with the results of my array for loop output:

```
  A = Float64.(reshape(1.0:81.0,9,9))
  # initialize output
  B = zeros(Int64, 2, 9)
  j = 1
  for j in 1:size(A,2) # loop cols
    out = [sum(A[:,j]),j]
    out = reshape(out,2,1) # make column to append
    # append out to the B
    global B = hcat(B,out) # this grows...
  end
```

I initialized     `B = zeros(Int64, 2, 9)`

same dims as the expected output of the `sum` operation.

in my real world example - I am iterating through j, columns and, i rows - the output is then an array... rather than use `hcat()` to append the array to my output can I do it with indexing?

In the above it uses `hcat()` which will then append to the existing B so it grows. I have since tried initializg with rows 2 and cols 0 so `hcat()` builds to correct output dim:

```
B = zeros(Int64, 2, 0)
```

I am doubting if `hcat()` will be memory efficient (excuse using global for example sakes) - if I couldn't do it with indexing I can populate it for another inner loop at my [i,j]. But perhaps someone has a way I can append an array as a column to existing pre initialized output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation is to pre-allocate `B` and fill it afterwards. I wrap the code in a function as it simplifies benchmarking:

```
function f2()
    A = reshape(1:81,9,9)
    B = zeros(Int64, 2, 9 + size(A,2))
    for j in 1:size(A,2) # loop cols
        B[:, j + 9] .= (sum(view(A, :, j)), j)
    end
    B
end
```

Your old code is:

```
function f1()
    A = Float64.(reshape(1.0:81.0,9,9))
    B = zeros(Int64, 2, 9)
    j = 1
    for j in 1:size(A,2) # loop cols
        out = [sum(A[:,j]),j]
        out = reshape(out,2,1) # make column to append
        # append out to the B
        B = hcat(B,out)
    end
    B
end
```

And here is a comparison:

```
julia> @btime f1()
  8.567 μs (83 allocations: 7.72 KiB)
2×18 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  45.0  126.0  207.0  288.0  369.0  450.0  531.0  612.0  693.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0    6.0    7.0    8.0    9.0

julia> @btime f2()
  73.662 ns (1 allocation: 368 bytes)
2×18 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  45  126  207  288  369  450  531  612  693
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
```

And you can see that the difference is very significant.

Some more minor comments to your original code:

- there is no need to call `Float64.` on `reshape(1.0:81.0,9,9)`, the object already holds elements that have `Float64` values
- in your code there was an inconsistency that initilally `B` held `Int64` and `A` held `Float64` - i have made this consistent (I chose `Int64`, but equally well you could use `Float64`)
- `sum(A[:,j])` unnecessarily allocated a new object; it is faster to use a `view`
- You did not have to call `reshape(out,2,1)` on `out` before `hcat` as vectors are already treated as columnar objects

Comment: Great! I certainly learned more here. In general is hcat() an effective use of memory? As it builds the matrix as its running - and i see you are populating the pre initialized. Thanks

Comment: repeated use of `hcat` is inefficient. If you have a collection of arrays you want to `hcat` use `reduce` like this. Assume you have `a = [[1,2] for i in 1:100]`. Then to `hcat` all of them efficiently write `reduce(hcat, a)`. In this way Julia will perform all needed allocations in one shot. What I did is yet a bit more efficient, because I preallocated everything manually and this allowed me to avoid creation of arrays inside the loop and replace them with a tuple (which does not allocate).